# How to convert WinBioCaptureSample to an image

Tags: image-processing, windows-7, biometrics

My problem is this: I'm given a data structure of binary data of type WINBIO_BIR_DATA (http://207.46.172.252/en-us/library/dd401649(VS.85).aspx) which is a c struct I believe. How would I convert it to an image?

It seems it give me some kind of size? Anyone have any ideas on how to convert this into an image I can parse and use?

Answer (score 1):

The `WINBIO_BIR_DATA` is for vendor-specific data.

If you want an image, it'll be in the [`WINBIO_BIR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd401648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s `StandardDataBlock` if the `HeaderBlock`'s Type is set to `WINBIO_ANSI_381_FORMAT_TYPE`.

If you want to convert an ANSI 381 image to a DIB, you can probably find enough information online to close the gap.